# Why am I getting a "missing ) after argument list" when connecting to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, heroku, mtls

my MONGO_URI

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb+srv:${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@rybnetwork.sn5ae.mongodb.net/rybnetwork, {useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

I don't have a MONGO_URI in my dotenv.
I only have DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD and PORT

my error message:

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb+srv:${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@rybnetwork.sn5ae.mongodb.net/rybnetwork, {useNewUrlParser: true,
                         ^^^
```

or should I ignore correcting this since with Heroku I'd have to use MTLS PostgreSQL?

Just prior to the above error message, I received:

```
(node:174556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string at parseConnectionString
```

Comment: `mongodb+srv...` =/= `"mongodb+srv..."` you are missing the quotes. It is not interpreted as a string.

Comment: Thank you Tin, I will try that. Learning Postgres just to use as an add-on is a bit much. I literally only have time to learn something less complicated.